# A word for a period covering two years

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Specifically the phrase "two years".

Just like how you can say *two moons* for “two months”.

I've thought of: "two periods" but that doesn't seem right, and "two seasons" but not quite sure if it is correct.

Poetic or not as long as it would still be understandable to some extent.

The phrase goes something like this...

> For it [flower] has seen [two something].

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[Biennium](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/biennium): *a period of two years*

Comment: This is a great term! The OP might want to note that it isn't in casual use--it's more a term of art, most often used when talking about business or budget issues.

Comment: Curses! Beat me to it!

Comment: @nedibes "Biennium" is rare, but the adjective "biennial" is a well-known word (at least in BrE) and commonly used to describe plants which live for two years, flower in the second year, and then die. Compare "annual" which describes plants which grow, flower, and die in a single year.

Comment: @alephzero - Actually, "biennium" is quite often heard in the news in the US, since most states have a two-year cycle for their legislatures and budgeting laws.

Comment: At least in AmE, while correct this term is problematic because confusion between it and biannual (twice a year) is rampant.

Comment: ***bi-year*** might be understood a bit more readily. Hopefully, people won't think it means half a year (since *semi-year* would mean that).

Answer (score 50):

With your added context, I suggest "For it has seen two summers...". Or whatever specific season you want, really, since they occur once a year.

Comment: I would like to +1 this because it has better illustrative qualities. I can support this from several experiences in retail where we don't particularly compare things in years, but rather however many busy seasons we've been through. "Three Christmases" holds a lot more weight than 3 and a half years because it shows we endured more high-stress moments than simply "being there"

Comment: I agree that this is the most common way of poetically expressing "x years." A good example is Lord Capulet's line in _Romeo and Juliet_: "She hath not seen the change of fourteen years. / Let two more summers wither in their pride, / Ere we may think her ripe to be a bride."

Answer (score 0):

In the particular case of politics, especially U.S. politics, the phrase "***Congressional term***" would be appropriate - referring to the term of office of an elected Congressional Representative.